# When using entity framework Where does this syntax return all records locally before doing the where

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

```
db.AdDetails.Where( u => u.OwnerGUID == CurrentUserProviderKey)
```

I have an adDetails table that has an `OwnerGUID` field.

I want to pull out only ad details that belong to the currenly logged in user.

My query does not show any where clauses in the SQL when I look at it in the debugger.

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my statement and if all rows in the table will be brought back then all 10K records put though a where on the webserver?

I am really new to this.

Comment: How do you produce the SQL string? with the .ToTraceString() method?

Comment: That looks like a correct statement. Try db.AdDetails.Where(u => u.OwnerGUID == CurrentUserProviderKey).ToList.Count and compare that to the actual number of records that you would expect for that guid.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Where` extension method will filter down the results.

Queries in Entity Framweork are not executed until you iterate over them. If you do:

```
var query = db.Where(u => u.OwnerGUID == key);
```

This does not execute the query. When you do the following:

```
var list = list.ToList();
```

OR

```
foreach( var item in query) { ... }
```

That is when the query will be executed in SQL. The results should be filtered with your WHERE clause at this point.

Comment: This gave me an idea how the command could differ in the debugger from it's expected behavior. If you hover over the db.AddDetails portion of the statement and evaluate it, the `.Where` clause is ignored. See if the SQL displays correctly in the debugger if you assign the whole query to a variable first and than evaluate the contents of that variable.